# runTaskTimer and PlayerListener not working

Tags: java, oop, minecraft, bukkit

```
public class Taserr extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {


@Override
public void onEnable() {
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}

int i=0;
int x=1;
double yy=0;
int z;

public void PlayerListener(EventHandle plugin) {
    plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
}


@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
final Player player = event.getPlayer();

World world = player.getWorld();

if (player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().equals(Material.GOLDEN_SWORD));

if (event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) || event.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) && player.getInventory().contains(Material.FIRE_CHARGE)) {
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        double t = 0;
        Location loc = player.getLocation();
        Vector direction = loc.getDirection().normalize();
    public void run() {
        t=t+0.1;
    double x = direction.getX() * t;
    double y = direction.getY() * t + 1;
    double z = direction.getZ() * t;
    loc.add(x,y,z);
    player.spawnParticle(Particle.CRIT_MAGIC, x, y, z, 5, 0, 0, 0);
    loc.subtract(x,y,z);

    if (t>100) {
        this.cancel();
    }   
    }

    }.runTaskTimer(EventHandle.getInstance(), 0, 1);



}

}


private static Plugin getInstance() {
    return null;
}

}
```

I'm partially a beginner in programming, so I am kinda stuck here. getInstance() on the bottom was the only thing I could do to correct the error, which the only thing was to create a method. PlayerListener was returning errors unless I put void in in. I have seen some videos and void apparently shouldn't go there. How can I correct this error?

Comment: I'm very confused what's going on. What exactly is your issue. Is the event firing, is it not?

Comment: I realized how much info I have left out. The event does not loop when I try runTaskTimer, mainly because the code gives me error messages leaving me to solve that problem before testing. It could also be the fact that the particle line isn't working either, because if I replace it with a test line of code like player.sendMessage(); it might work. If I replace EventHandle.getInstance() with this, it removes the error(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);` instead of `.runTaskTimer(EventHandle.getInstance(), 0, 1);`